# MVC5 asp.net Show Validation Error in tooltip when I use dialog form for Edit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I try use plugin from
https://bunjeeb.com/2014/06/03/mvc-tooltip-validation-using-jquery-and-bootstrap/

But Validation Error appeared under EditControl first time and once disappeared when I push the button "Save" and then like a tooltip when when I push the button "Save" second time

Please help me
Thanks a lot

**1. _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Moving Pro Services</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.validate.mvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Moving Pro Services", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Companies", "Index", "Companies")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("App Versions", "Index", "AppVersions")</li>
                                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                {
                                    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                                    {
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create User", "Register", "Account")</li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Moving Pro Services</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**2. View**

```
@model Maintenance.Models.AppVersion


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit App Version</h4>
        </div>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AppVersion1)

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group margin-bottom">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save changes" id="approve-btn" />
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("form input").tooltipValidation({
                placement: "right"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**3. Script for create dialog for Edit**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).on("click", ".modal-link", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal
                (
                {
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show'
                );

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a[data-modal]", function (e)
    {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function ()
        {
            $('#myModal').modal
            (
                {
                  keyboard: true
                }, 'show'
            );

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(window.document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('[autofocus]', this).focus();
        }.bind(this), 100);
    });
});


function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        var isValid = true; // assume all OK
        $('form').validate(); // perform validation on the form
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function (index, item) { // could change selector to suit e.g $('input, textarea').each(..            
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                isValid = false; // signal errors
                return false; // break out of loop   
            }
        });
        if (!isValid) {
            return false; // exit
        }
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {

                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    //location.reload();
                    alert(result.message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

**4. Model**

```
namespace Maintenance.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class AppVersion
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AppVersion()
        {
            this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        }

        [StringLength(40)]
        [Display(Name = "App Version")]
        public string AppVersion1 { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        [Display(Name = "App Version Description")]
        public string AppVersionDescription { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Creating Date")]
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**5. Plugin to show tooltip**

```js
/*
 *  Project: MVC Validation Framework
 *  Description: This plugin will convert client side validation elements to bootstrap tooltips
 *  Author: Ahmad Aqrabawi, Mohamed Aljaber
 *  License: MIT
 */

// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
    // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
    // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
    // can no longer be modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
    // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
    // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "tooltipValidation";
    var defaults = {
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function () {

            // Place initialization logic here
            // You already have access to the DOM element and
            // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
            // and this.options
            // you can add more functions like the one below and
            // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).

            var elem = $(this.element),
                name = elem.attr("name"),
                defaultBorderCss = elem.css('border'),
                tooltipPlacement = this.options.placement;

            if (name) {

                var errValElem = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + name + '"]');
                errValElem.hide();

                function onDOMSubtreeModified(errValElem) {

                    errValElem.bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {

                        elem.tooltip("destroy");
                        elem.siblings("div.tooltip").remove();

                        var isTooltipPluginAttached = elem.data("plugin_tooltipValidation");
                        if (!isTooltipPluginAttached) {
                            elem.tooltip({
                                'title': errValElem.text(),
                                'animation': 'true',
                                'placement': tooltipPlacement || 'top',
                                'trigger': 'focus'
                            });
                        }

                        if (errValElem.hasClass("field-validation-error")) {
                            elem.css('border', '1px solid red');
                        }
                        else {
                            elem.css('border', defaultBorderCss);
                            elem.tooltip('destroy');
                            elem.siblings("div.tooltip").remove();
                        }

                    });
                };
                function showTooltipOfError(event) {

                    var inputField = event.currentTarget;
                    if (errValElem.hasClass("field-validation-error") || errValElem.hasClass("field-error")) {

                        $(inputField).siblings("div.tooltip").remove();

                        $(inputField).tooltip({
                            'title': $(errValElem).text(),
                            'animation': 'true',
                            'placement': tooltipPlacement || 'top',
                            'trigger': 'focus'
                        });
                        $(inputField).tooltip('show')
                        $(".tooltip").addClass("error");
                    }
                };

                if (elem.is('select')) { //Handle tooltip on input type = select (DropdownList)
                    elem.on("focus mouseenter", function (event) {
                        showTooltipOfError(event);
                    });
                    elem.on("mouseleave", function (event) {
                        var inputField = event.currentTarget;
                        $(inputField).tooltip('hide');
                    });
                    onDOMSubtreeModified(errValElem);
                }
                else if (elem.attr('type') == 'date') { //Handle if input type = date
                    elem.on("focus mouseenter", function (event) {
                        showTooltipOfError(event);
                    });
                    elem.on("mouseleave", function (event) {
                        var inputField = event.currentTarget;
                        $(inputField).tooltip('hide');
                    });
                    elem.on("change", function (event) {
                        var inputField = event.currentTarget;
                        if ($(inputField).val() != "") {
                            elem.css('border', defaultBorderCss);
                            elem.tooltip('destroy');
                            elem.siblings("div.tooltip").remove();
                        }
                        else
                            elem.css('border', '1px solid red');
                    });
                    onDOMSubtreeModified(errValElem);
                }
                else if (elem.attr('type') == 'file') {
                    elem.on("focus mouseenter", function (event) {
                        showTooltipOfError(event);
                    });
                    elem.on("mouseleave", function (event) {
                        var inputField = event.currentTarget;
                        $(inputField).tooltip('hide');
                    });
                    onDOMSubtreeModified(errValElem);
                }
                else {
                    elem.on("focus", function (event) {
                        showTooltipOfError(event);
                    });
                    onDOMSubtreeModified(errValElem);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```